# Elastic search query with wildcard filter on field containing path values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to write an elastic search query that can allow me to search across multiple records based on wildcard on a field that contains value of path.
My data looks like this:

```
[{
    "_index": "my-data",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "fil.33dc27bd183c4b92a18d08d9525398d2",
    "_score": 0.0018758172,
    "_source": {
        "sizeInBytes": 1,
        "parentFolderId": "fol.844354089a8b4151577708d95305cbca",
        "type": "text/plain",
        "timeModified": "2021-07-30T04:50:37.687Z",
        "path": "/folder2/testfile.10.207",
        "storageTier": "Standard",
        "volumeId": "vol.fe502fc3c23246b51d1708d936facf5f",
        "timeCreated": "2021-07-30T04:50:37.687Z",
        "isUploaded": true,
        "eTag": "5058f1af8388633f609cadb75a75dc9d",
        "id": "fil.33dc27bd183c4b92a18d08d9525398d2",
        "dataType": "File",
        "volumeName": "kctest2",
        "name": "testfile.10.207",
        "archiveStatus": "None",
        "status": "Available"
    }
}, {
    "_index": "my-data",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "fil.20935f2a158248c4582d08d95305cbca",
    "_score": 0.0018758172,
    "_source": {
        "sizeInBytes": 1,
        "parentFolderId": "fol.844354089a8b4151577708d95305cbca",
        "type": "text/plain",
        "timeModified": "2021-07-30T04:50:39.035Z",
        "path": "/folder2/testfile.10.70",
        "storageTier": "Standard",
        "volumeId": "vol.fe502fc3c23246b51d1708d936facf5f",
        "timeCreated": "2021-07-30T04:50:39.035Z",
        "isUploaded": true,
        "eTag": "5058f1af8388633f609cadb75a75dc9d",
        "id": "fil.20935f2a158248c4582d08d95305cbca",
        "dataType": "File",
        "volumeName": "kctest2",
        "name": "testfile.10.70",
        "status": "Available"
    }
}, {
    "_index": "my-data",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "fil.a4912bfbbad84952a19108d9525398d2",
    "_score": 0.0018758172,
    "_source": {
        "sizeInBytes": 1,
        "parentFolderId": "fol.65037e6e669b49b356b408d95305cbca",
        "type": "text/plain",
        "timeModified": "2021-07-30T04:50:38.101Z",
        "path": "/folder1/testfile.101.195",
        "volumeId": "vol.fe502fc3c23246b51d1708d936facf5f",
        "timeCreated": "2021-07-30T04:50:38.101Z",
        "isUploaded": true,
        "eTag": "5058f1af8388633f609cadb75a75dc9d",
        "id": "fil.a4912bfbbad84952a19108d9525398d2"
        "dataType": "File",
        "volumeName": "kctest2",
        "name": "testfile.101.195",
        "archiveStatus": "None",
        "status": "Available"
    }
}]
```

I am trying to create a query like this:

```
https://mycompanyelasticsearch.com/my-data/_search?q=volumeId:vol.fe502fc3c23246b51d1708d936facf5f AND dataType:"File" AND path:"/folder2/*"
```

with intention to find all the records which are:

1. Associated with volumeId : vol.fe502fc3c23246b51d1708d936facf5f
2. Are of dataType : File
3. Also all the files that are stored at path value /folder2/*

so instead of specifying the absolute path value, I was trying to use wildcard * at the end that it will allow me to search all the files under the /folder2/ path.

But it doesn't return expected results, infact doesn't return any data.

This query works with absolute path value:

```
https://mycompanyelasticsearch.com/my-data/_count?q=volumeId:vol.fe502fc3c23246b51d1708d936facf5f AND dataType:File AND path:"/folder2/testfile.10.70"
```

But with wildcard it doesn't.

If its relevant here is the info about the path field mapping:

```
{
    "my-data": {
        "mappings": {
            "path": {
                "full_name": "path",
                "mapping": {
                    "path": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "rawlower": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "normalizer": "lowercase"
                            },
                            "tree": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "path_analyzer"
                            },
                            "tree_level": {
                                "type": "token_count",
                                "store": true,
                                "analyzer": "path_level_analyzer",
                                "enable_position_increments": false
                            }
                        },
                        "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Regards,
Vikas

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue, I should be using this:

```
https://mycompanyelasticsearch.com/my-data/_search?q=volumeId:vol.fe502fc3c23246b51d1708d936facf5f AND dataType:"File" AND path:/folder2/*
```

without the double quotes and then it works.