# Elastic search count query based on field with value containing filesystem path

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, amazon-elasticsearch

I asked this question earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69490576/elastic-search-query-with-wildcard-filter-on-field-containing-path-values)
However I realized my mistake very soon as I tried the solution with more data.

So I am back to square one. So I am hoping to ask this question again and get more insights.

My task is still the same but more precisely to get counts of documents based on multiple values including a path field that contains values like system file paths.

My example data look likes this:

```
{
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 3,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 15.9074545,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "stage-data-20210728115212095",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "fil.31c425766287497ec5a508d995d1ce36",
                "_score": 15.9074545,
                "_source": {
                    "header_action": "uploaded",
                    "partition": 7,
                    "offset": 11382619,
                    "volumeId": "vol.e144f0bc59914725528f08d995ebd8c3",
                    "lambdaLagMs": 0,
                    "id": "fil.31c425766287497ec5a508d995d1ce36",
                    "name": "sampleFile.txt",
                    "parentFolderId": "fol.6357e749063445b0c5a408d995d1ce36",
                    "volumeName": "test-vol-b2ee569932dd470788ebc70e6f15bf36",
                    "type": "text/plain",
                    "path": "/test_Folder-ed9cc1294ba841f98fa986be7ac38813/Folder1/sampleFile.txt",
                    "timeCreated": "2021-10-23T06:10:45.287Z",
                    "timeModified": "2021-10-23T06:10:45.287Z",
                    "sizeInBytes": 26,
                    "isUploaded": true,
                    "archiveStatus": "None",
                    "storageTier": "Standard",
                    "eTag": "ed6a6e795564952d4d9707e7dc91c6a6",
                    "format": "TXT",
                    "status": "Available",
                    "recordDateTime": "2021-10-23 06:10:47.268",
                    "recordTurnAroundTimeMs": 2629.375,
                    "dataType": "File"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "stage-data-20210728115212095",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "fil.6075863c66464a2cc5a608d995d1ce36",
                "_score": 15.500043,
                "_source": {
                    "header_action": "uploaded",
                    "partition": 15,
                    "offset": 11393012,
                    "volumeId": "vol.e144f0bc59914725528f08d995ebd8c3",
                    "lambdaLagMs": 0,
                    "id": "fil.6075863c66464a2cc5a608d995d1ce36",
                    "name": "testFile.txt",
                    "parentFolderId": "fol.230c9c8861fa40640cc808d995d1b210",
                    "volumeName": "test-vol-b2ee569932dd470788ebc70e6f15bf36",
                    "type": "text/plain",
                    "path": "/test_Folder-ed9cc1294ba841f98fa986be7ac38813/testFile.txt",
                    "timeCreated": "2021-10-23T06:10:45.286Z",
                    "timeModified": "2021-10-23T06:10:45.286Z",
                    "sizeInBytes": 23,
                    "isUploaded": true,
                    "archiveStatus": "None",
                    "storageTier": "Standard",
                    "eTag": "2b9f6fc56449eb68b4fa5c5da127c5be",
                    "format": "TXT",
                    "status": "Available",
                    "recordDateTime": "2021-10-23 06:10:47.284",
                    "recordTurnAroundTimeMs": 2628.936,
                    "dataType": "File"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "stage-data-20210728115212095",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "fil.27a781dc81554811576308d995d1ce3c",
                "_score": 15.500043,
                "_source": {
                    "header_action": "uploaded",
                    "partition": 6,
                    "offset": 11377991,
                    "volumeId": "vol.e144f0bc59914725528f08d995ebd8c3",
                    "lambdaLagMs": 0,
                    "id": "fil.27a781dc81554811576308d995d1ce3c",
                    "name": "smallfile.txt",
                    "parentFolderId": "fol.6ac9ecb11dae4ebd576208d995d1ce3c",
                    "volumeName": "test-vol-b2ee569932dd470788ebc70e6f15bf36",
                    "type": "text/plain",
                    "path": "/test_Folder-ed9cc1294ba841f98fa986be7ac38813/Folder1/Folder2/smallfile.txt",
                    "timeCreated": "2021-10-23T06:10:45.294Z",
                    "timeModified": "2021-10-23T06:10:45.294Z",
                    "sizeInBytes": 1249,
                    "isUploaded": true,
                    "archiveStatus": "None",
                    "storageTier": "Standard",
                    "eTag": "c6e9338f9e54e39b52dd853908a1aecd",
                    "status": "Available",
                    "recordDateTime": "2021-10-23 06:10:47.276",
                    "recordTurnAroundTimeMs": 2629.8689999999997,
                    "dataType": "File"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the count of documents using NEST c# library. Here is my sample code:

```
        var elasticSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("https://myelasticurl/"))
                .DefaultIndex("stage-data");

            var client = new ElasticClient(elasticSettings);
            var folderPrefix = "/test_Folder-ed9cc1294ba841f98fa986be7ac38813/Folder1/Folder2/";

            Func<CountDescriptor<dynamic>, ICountRequest> countQueryFilter = q => q.Query(q =>
                q.Match(m => m.Field("volumeId").Query("vol.e144f0bc59914725528f08d995ebd8c3"))
                && q.Match(m => m.Field("dataType").Query("File")) &&
                q.Wildcard(m => m.Field("path").Value($"{folderPrefix}*")));
            
            

         var countResponse= client.CountAsync(countQueryFilter);
         Console.WriteLine(countResponse.Result.Count);
```

Here is the mapping of the path field

```
{
    "stage-data-20210728115212095": {
        "mappings": {
            "path": {
                "full_name": "path",
                "mapping": {
                    "path": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "rawlower": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "normalizer": "lowercase"
                            },
                            "tree": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "path_analyzer"
                            },
                            "tree_level": {
                                "type": "token_count",
                                "store": true,
                                "analyzer": "path_level_analyzer",
                                "enable_position_increments": false
                            }
                        },
                        "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I only search for volumeId and dataType, I can get the results just fine. Even for path field, for the dataset where I have files at the root folder for example /folder1/mytxt.txt etc, the query works.
Only when I have files under multiple level deep like in the above example when I try to search for path like this /test_Folder-ed9cc1294ba841f98fa986be7ac38813/Folder1/Folder2/, I get 0 result count.

At this point I am not sure if I need to tweak the mapping settings of this field to make it more search friendly something like suggested [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer-examples.html) or if I am just using the wrong method to search this.

Please note I did try following methods for the path searching:

- WildCard
- Term
- Regexp
- Match

I got the same results of 0 record returned.

Please suggest what I am missing, thanks for your help in advance.

I am using NEST 7.13.0 on .NET core 3.1.

Regards,
Vikas

Comment: Are you looking for exact match on the value of `path` field?

Comment: Hi Nishant, actually not exact match but sort of wildcard. One of my colleague was able to find a solution that works. I will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleague helped with this and the solution works nicely.
Here is the sample code:

```
 var elasticSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("https://myelasticurl/"))
                .DefaultIndex("stage-data");

            var client = new ElasticClient(elasticSettings);
            var folderPrefix = "/test_Folder-ed9cc1294ba841f98fa986be7ac38813/Folder1/Folder2/";

            Func<CountDescriptor<dynamic>, ICountRequest> countQueryFilter = q => q.Query(q =>
                q.Match(m => m.Field("volumeId").Query("vol.e144f0bc59914725528f08d995ebd8c3"))
                && q.Match(m => m.Field("dataType").Query("File")) &&
                q.Prefix(m => m.Field("path.raw").Value($"{folderPrefix}")));
            
            

         var countResponse= client.CountAsync(countQueryFilter);
         Console.WriteLine(countResponse.Result.Count);
```

So basically needed to use Prefix filter along with path.raw that is defined in the mapping.